Power at pump house but won't run water pump
We lost water a few days ago and went and bought a new pump and everything after checking and making sure it wasn't anything more simple. We bought everything new including a new box. When we hooked everything up to test before we put it down our well nothing works. We tried everything we can think of. There is power there but it fluctuates, and we brought both motors to our shop to test and they both worked there. What am I missing? Points are clean, checked all spliced areas, even hooked directly to box. I am at a complete loss.

What is the distance between pump and power source (e.g., main panel)? What voltage does the pump require? What voltage do you measure with the pump off? Any possibility of wire damage between pump and power source?

"There is power there but it fluctuates" could mean that you are using a digital voltmeter and reading a phantom voltage. This could indicate a broken wire, corroded splice or disconnected terminal. Move some piece of equipment to the pumphouse that uses the voltage that your pump uses, connect it and see if it works. If it does not, the original pump may not have been defective at all.

Thank you, we were able to isolate where the power problem is. We have to dig up the line and fix a wire.
